# Book series with a magical community where characters have different talents

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a book series about a magical community. Each community members has a magical power. There was a book about a women who could see the future, one who could control the weather and an autistic women going to the community to learn magic from them. I believe the first book was about a character who was a real estate agent. Also, there is a little deaf boy who has hearing aids and can do a bunch of stuff.

PS: For the women who can see the future, she was in a mental institution and couldn't control her power so they eventually get rid of her power, but she still stayed in the community. I have been looking for a while but just couldn't remember the name. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: When did you read this? Paperback or hardback? Do you know approximately how many books in the series? Did the magic require gestures? Components? Prayer? Equations?

Comment: Please take a look at the guidelines at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info for more questions you ought to try to answer.

Comment: [Written in Red](https://allaboutromance.com/book-review/written-in-red/)?

Comment: I read the books several years ago so I cannot remember whether it was paperback or hardback. But I remember their powers were elemental, like they could control fire, earth, weather, etc. Also, I think the books were self published, if it is any help.

Comment: @Asha111 You seem to have created two separate accounts; please consider [merging them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can do things like edit or comment on your own question without needing anyone else's approval.